# Translate instance in "World Space" with LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, translate-animation

I am using LibGDX for 3D animation, and I'm not sure what is the intended way of translating objects in `world space` coordinates.

Consider the following code:

```
myInstance.transform.rotate( new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 90 );
myInstance.transform.translate( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
```

This will translate the object's position along the Z-axis in `model space`. Since the object is rotated 90 degree, this means it will move along the X-axis in `world space`.

Instead of translating the object in `model space`, I would like to translate it in `world space`. As far as I can tell, LibGDX doesn't have a straightforward way to accomplish this. The best solution I have found is this:

```
Vector3 position = myInstance.transform.getTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
myInstance.transform.setTranslation( position.x + x, position.y + y, position.z + z);
```

This code is fairly simple to use, but I would think this feature would be built into LibGDX. Is there a better way to achieve `world space` translation?

Comment: `Matrix4#trn(x,y,z)` http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#trn-float-float-float-

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I figured it would end up being something absurdly simple. 

Just curious, would the LibGDX folks be appreciative of pull requests improving the JavaDocs? The docs are generally good, but I occasionally come across something that is undocumented or unclear.